# Running exe on website from cmd

Tags: cmd, client-server, webclient, executable, server-side

I have a website anomoz.com where i have uploaded an exe file in the directory 'anomoz.com/home/createFolder.exe'. This exe will create a folder named 'Console' in the working directory when run. Is there a way i can run this exe through cmd or any other way that i can try?

I tried "cmd /k 'start https://anomoz.com/home/createFolder.exe'" but it just opens the file for download and doesnt execute it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No that's impossible, why can't the code of your website create the folder, it's unclear to me what you want to achieve here. What environment are you talking about, asp.net?

Comment: I dont want to run this exe from my server. I want to run this exe as a user who knows the location of exe, but doesnt have access to the administration of the website.

Comment: OK, What language are you using?

Comment: exe is written in pthon. what other language ae u talking about?

Comment: The language of your website, I assume you have some server side code? What is the OS of the host?

Comment: it has been written in PHP

Comment: You will need to find out how to run an exe from php, see for instance : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13446492/run-a-exe-with-input-parameters-from-php-web-page

Comment: the OS hosting is using is Linux

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18714207/executing-exe-file-using-php-on-linux-server